# How should I migrate a model?

Tags: django, django-models

django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on databas I e ' default ' . C : \ Users \ mamma tutorial \ django \ newsite

I tried to migrate a model, but when I run the command in the terminal, this problem occurs

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project

Comment: please provide that model

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete your everything in your migration folder except `__init__.py` and then drop database then re-run migrations